# Problems Making a TableView Fade

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

Using `UIView animateWithDuration`, I'm setting a `UITableView` alpha to 0 so that it fades away in a disappearing animation. However, I'm noticing that when the `UITableView` fades, there are areas on each cell that turn black before fading. If there is an image, the whole area behind it turns black while fading, and usually the inset space on both the left and right edge turn black. I've tried setting all of the background colors of the `UITableViewCell` subviews to white and it still doesn't work.

This tableview is not embedded in a UITableViewController. Instead, it's a separate floating tableView that I'm using as a menu.

Here is an example of what happens when it's fading:

[image]

Here is the code I'm using as well

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:ImageViewControllerBarsAnimationDuration delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^
    {
            if (self.menu.superview)
            {
                self.menu.alpha = 0;
            }
    } 
completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
            if (self.menu.superview)
            {
                [self.menu removeFromSuperview];
                self.menu.alpha = 1;
            }   
}];
```

+

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

    if (tableViewCell == nil) 
    {
        tableViewCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    [[tableViewCell textLabel] setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Helvetica-Bold" size: 17]];
    [[tableViewCell textLabel] setText: [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:0]];
    [[tableViewCell imageView] setImage: [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:1]];

    return tableViewCell;
}
```

Comment: Could you take a screenshot and post it so we can get a better idea of the problem? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you fade the table view's superview instead? If that works just embed the table view in a UIView and away you go.

Comment: @rog - good thought, but it still does the same thing

Comment: Very strange, I just quickly tested with a sample tableview app from Apple (TheElements) and the whole table fades out as expected. Maybe toggle slow animations on the simulator to see if it gives you a hint of what is getting "out of sync" during the fade? Otherwise we'll need to see some code, probably what's in your custom cells is what's causing the problem. Have you tried replacing the custom cells with default ones to see if the problem persists?

Comment: Can you provide the code in which you have tried to fade the table??That will help in getting the solution easily..

Comment: Rog - I'm actually not using custom cells, I posted the code above.

Comment: @iPhoneDeveloper - I posted some code.

Comment: @qegal - Sorry it took so long, but updated with screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DTS gave me a solution to this, have to do the following:

```
self.myTableView.backgroundView = nil;
self.myTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Then inside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method have to do this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *kOneCellID = @"cellID";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kOneCellID];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:kOneCellID] autorelease];
        cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
        cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score -4):

What is self.menu? If you put tableView in its place it works exactly fine.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:ImageViewControllerBarsAnimationDuration delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^
    {
            if (tableView.superview)
            {
                tableView.alpha = 0;
            }
    } 
completion:^(BOOL finished)
{
            if (tableView.superview)
            {
                [tableView removeFromSuperview];
                tableView.alpha = 1;
            }   
}];
```

Comment: self.menu is the property which stores my tableView. Changing the variable name will not change the outcome at all. I'm not using a UITableViewController where the UITableView is stored in the tableView variable. I'm using a separate floating tableView within a UIViewController.

Comment: @CoDEFRo: Then instead of fading the whole view you can try to fade the cell background and then remove the view from superview.and you should have specified in the question about self.menu. That would have helped me get a +1 instead of -1.:)